# How to mark dependencies as external in WebPack when those are not imported with '*'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

How can I specify office-ui-fabric-react as an external dependency in **Webpack**?

I am importing dependencies as below in my TypeScript project (**Note:** that I am only importing the modules I need) -

```
import { Dialog, DialogType, DialogFooter } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dialog';
import { PrimaryButton, DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
```

Current external configuration in **webpack.config.js** which works for React & ReactDOM but doesn't work for Fabric.

```
   externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        "office-ui-fabric-react": "office-ui-fabric-react"
    }
```

Do I need to specify it somehow differently when I am importing only selective modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`externals` field of webpack works as following: if you specify `office-ui-fabric-react` as external, only import to `office-ui-fabric-react` will be marked as external.

In your case, you are doing a deep import (why?) to `office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dialog` so it, not matches `office-ui-fabric-react` therefore it was not considered as external.

You have 2 options:

1. Define each one of the deep imports as external, you may use the [function syntax of externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#function)
2. Use `import {Dialog} from 'office-ui-fabric-react'`

#### Examples:

Usage of such import

```
import get from 'lodash/get';
```

will require you to add `lodash/get` to externals, with lodash it is ease,

```
...
externals: {
   'lodash/get': '_.get'    
}
...
```

Usually, it is not a good practice to put internal stuff as external.

Comment: Any example for option#1 you can share?

 Btw, I am doing deep impact to not include everything and just pick the selected components.

Comment: I've added an example for option 1, There is 0 impact to include all, cause it will be marked as external. meaning you are responsible to put (the entire lib) on the global vie CDN link or any other mean.

Comment: Marking externals as your suggested example worked. Thanks!
Btw, I do need to do this because I am publishing a package which is going to be used by another app which has the similar dependencies.

Comment: For reference: Here is what I ended up adding to make the dependency truly external - 
        'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dialog': '_.Dialog, _.DialogType, _.DialogFooter',
        'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button': '_.PrimaryButton, _.DefaultButton'

Answer (score 1):

Posting how the externals looked after applying suggestion from @felixmosh which resolved the issue for me. Now, none of the office-ui-fabric-react components are getting added in the final JS file.

```
externals: {
   "react": "React",
   "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
   'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dialog': '_.Dialog, _.DialogType, _.DialogFooter',
   'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button': '_.PrimaryButton, _.DefaultButton'
}
```

Comment: Why was the '_' required?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack-external-import would let you dynamically manage externals without losing the standalone capabilities. https://itnext.io/micro-frontend-architecture-dynamic-import-chunks-from-another-webpack-bundle-at-runtime-1132d8cb6051